# Load document directory image into web view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiimage

I have a an Xcode project with `UIWebView`. Now I need to load an image from document directory to that webview. How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString  *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                          [NSString stringWithFormat: @"/imageName.png"]];


    [myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",imagePath] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: This isn't working !!!

Comment: It works ... you might need to add ATS exception in info.plist