# inject image from document directory to a html in ios

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I have an html page. Inside which I have to load the image using a document directory url. Here is the html and javascript.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function fetchObjDetails(scanImageLeftURL, scanImageRightURL)
    {
        /* left image */
        var leftImg = new Image;
        leftImg.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('left_foot').src = this.src;
        }   
        leftImg.src = scanImageLeftURL;

        /* right image */
        var rightImg = new Image;
        rightImg.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('right_foot').src = this.src;
        }   
        rightImg.src = scanImageRightURL;
    }
    </script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div class="container padall">
      <img alt="Left Foot" id="left_foot" src="" width="30%" />
      <img alt="Right Foot" id="right_foot" src="" width="30%" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the objective c code I used to trigger the function.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *fullURL = @"some live url";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    webFormView.delegate=self;
    [webFormView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

    -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
        NSString *leftImgURL = @"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/95736371-EA3D-475D-942D-835A037F8795/Documents/LeftImage_1454405366000.jpg";

        NSString *rightImgURL = @"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/95736371-EA3D-475D-942D-835A037F8795/Documents/RightImage_1454405366000.jpg";

        NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fetchObjDetails('%@','%@')", leftImgURL, rightImgURL];

        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
    }
```

But I'm not getting any image in the html end. Can somebody tell me is it the right process or not?

Comment: Just checked your code seems working, I replaced path to images to one I found in internet and yes, I seee two images in webView

Comment: And you FOR sure shoudn't hardcode path to "documetns" directory, check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367212/load-document-directory-image-into-web-view or google how to do it in a correct way

Comment: so I guess if you want to load local images -> src of html element should start from file://path_to_file

Comment: @Injectios : I hardcoded the documented directory url for understanding purpose.

Comment: @Injectios : But how to edit a html and inject an image after the webview finished loading?

Comment: try to add file:// to your path to image, you don't actually need to update html

Comment: @Injectios: I tried but no luck.

Comment: I tried with file:// to become file:///var/mobile/.... and it worked.